# What is the name of twodots design

Tags: website-design

[image: Twodots BG]

Hi, I just love this kind of design and I wanna know if exist specific name for this.

Comment: Flat design is probably your safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Vector illustration, cartoon, flat illustration.